# Use SQL Server PIVOT Result in EF Core

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, pivot-table

My goal is to export the result of the query to a CSV file that the user can download.

My current SQL Server translations table looks like this:

| Id | LanguageCode | TextKey | TextValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 71-a6b7-4dc6-9e86-3800905a4020 | en | d2781c1b-b70e-489b-bb22-03f72f870a5c | Hello |
| c6f05a00-d69e-4b29-aa82-095fb00478b7 | es | d2781c1b-b70e-489b-bb22-03f72f870a5c | Hola |
| f9d8a87d-c191-48d4-b82c-ae5be6f7cea7 | fr | d2781c1b-b70e-489b-bb22-03f72f870a5c | Bonjour |
| 9927b4dc-a77a-4cad-8b0b-d0c6efb2ccc7 | en | fb9baaa8-b1f7-45e8-93d9-8d6387826322 | I love cheese. |
| 0119a482-a3cb-4558-a5fc-21b8ad441456 | es | fb9baaa8-b1f7-45e8-93d9-8d6387826322 | Me encanta el queso. |
| dabfb932-8273-41bc-979e-cc13d120837f | en | 11663f5a-de8d-4030-b57a-476579976e3f | Where is the bathroom? |
| a8c77d84-e56a-4f52-a9f6-9ca06a4492d5 | es | 11663f5a-de8d-4030-b57a-476579976e3f | ¿Dónde está el baño? |
| 378bb35c-53c0-4247-97b6-fb4a3a4f1647 | en | 9f0e0b56-01ce-460b-88f3-3e73f7d99c24 | How do I do this query? |

The goal is for the output of this query to be:

| TextKey | en | es | fr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d2781c1b-b70e-489b-bb22-03f72f870a5c | Hello | Hola | Bonjour |
| fb9baaa8-b1f7-45e8-93d9-8d6387826322 | I love cheese. | Me encanta el queso. |  |
| 11663f5a-de8d-4030-b57a-476579976e3f | Where is the bathroom? | ¿Dónde está el baño? |  |
| 9f0e0b56-01ce-460b-88f3-3e73f7d99c24 | How do I do this query? |  |  |

A couple of key notes:

- The unique constraint on this table is (LanguageCode, TextKey)
- There will be an unknown number of unique LanguageCode values.
- In the output example, a blank value indicates there was no corresponding table record for that TextKey/LanguageCode combination

I am currently producing the query output I'm looking for with:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(LanguageCode) 
            from dbo.eConsentContentLocalizations
            group by LanguageCode
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT * FROM   
(
SELECT 
    TextKey,
    LanguageCode,
    TextValue
FROM 
    dbo.Translations
) b
PIVOT(
    Max(TextValue)
    FOR LanguageCode IN ('  + @cols + ')
) p '


execute sp_executesql @query
```

What is the recommended way to get this response dataset into a response object in C# using EF Core? Then I can do the work of converting to CSV and returning to user.

Comment: Look [here](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/1475)

Answer (score 0):

That's a "dynamic pivot" and EF will never support that unless you specify the columns at design time.

But it's unnecessary to perform this transformation in SQL.  Just fetch the unpivoted tabular data sorted by TextKey and build the CSV from iterating the data.